# How common are IQ tests during job interviews?

Tags: interviewing, united-states

During my interview I was asked by one of the three people interviewing me that I would be required to take an IQ test after the interview. I was a bit shocked as I was never asked this during any other interviews I've been in. How common is this?

Comment: Reliable statistics would be hard to find. Anecdotal evidence suggests "uncommon, possibly rare."

Comment: In the U.S., testing is potentially legally problematic and could lead to discrimination claims (though not outright illegal if it is relevant to the job).  I think this is one reason it's rare in this context.

Comment: I'd be worried about a company that would use such a poor performance predictor.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z it's far from clear that IQ tests are a "poor performance predictor".  Actually research has shown a strong correlation between IQ tests and job performance, though other people question how good the research is.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4557354/

Comment: @dan1111 I've seen too many clever people being unable to fulfill elementary tasks (in my programming domain) to consider IQ like a good predictor. Of course, the real problem that lies behind is that most tests are poor predictors, not only IQ tests. But IQ seems even worse to me, as it's really broad, and not narrowed to the real job people will have to make. I may be wrong on the topic, but tests are overall weak, and so are IQ tests.

Comment: @dan1111 based on that assumtion I would have great performances. However I can garantee you I would make for an poor electrician.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griggs_v._Duke_Power_Co.

Comment: Depends on the industry, culture of the region you apply in, and culture of the company management. I've read about it being done, but never heard of anyone I know who actually encountered it. But the world's a large place.

Answer (score 6):

I've heard of it *once*. Actually, I've heard it from a friend who applied for a job and had to do an IQ test, and then he applied for another job and was given *an identical IQ test* and he got the job - the second company was impressed by his test results.

Comment: I've had one once, over 20 years ago at a large multinational as a fresh graduate in IT.  Apparently I topped the scores and was offered the role.  Guess the bar must have been pretty low that day ;)

Comment: @janeS, funny you mention that because I'm starting my career in IT lol

Comment: If he didn't have to do them on the same day when he still had all the answers memorized, it was probably either not an IQ test or a very crappy one. IQ tests don't have an "aha" moment. They are plain brain work, every time you do them.

Comment: One day apart, and he had a good memory.

Answer (score 3):

It is more common at workplaces, where required education level is below college. The knowledge area is very wide to cover, and an employer may wish to employ someone who shows certain skills, but without interviewing every candidate beforehand. Recently I heard this to occour at financial positions for a local country bank.

By the way, the positions I have applied so far (required minimum college level), more or less included some logic test but during the interview. So it is still coming up, but not in a mass-tested way.

Comment: Do you have evidence that below-college positions do IQ tests? Most positions like that don't actually care what your IQ is.

Comment: Maybe if you score too high, they figure this job is not a good match for you.

Comment: @DJClayworth: It is tricky, what you ask, because here the employers keep the recruiting process as private information, so a real source would be a professional recruiter, but I don't have that one in my reach, who would share this infomration in public web. We collect these experiences from friends...I can ask my friend to share this experience with you, if you insist. Still it sounds convenient in our country to do IQ tests for those who have paper about finishing a high school in general.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of it, but it must happen judging by comments. So it must be very rare in most places.

I used to do something a bit similar in that I made candidates write something small just to make sure they can actually read and write if they have a degree from the local university here.

Comment: "write something small" - Did you get depressed by the FizzBuzz results so you lowered the bar? ;)

Comment: @Peter I got depressed from the 'write something small results'. They stopped scaling marks here one year and over 90% of the students failed first year, so they reintroduced scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a formal IQ test, or just a couple of questions that are sort of like an IQ test?

I've never been asked to take a "real" IQ test for a job, nor do I recall anyone I know saying they had.

I've had a few job interviews where they gave me some sort of quiz. I don't recall ever being asked IQ-test-like questions, but the idea that someone would include a few in a quiz seems less unlikely to me.

So: I don't have any statistics, but my own anecdotal experience is: never. As others here seem to be saying the same, yeah, I'd say it's pretty rare.